# Assembly descriptor: Unpack-include exclusively?

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

### Description

While working through a large multi-module project I discovered a custom [Assembly Descriptor](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) file. What I don't fully understand is the following, especially the `includes` section.

```
<assembly [...]>
    [...]
    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <unpack>true</unpack>
            <unpackOptions>
                <includes>
                    <include>defaults*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </unpackOptions>
            <outputFileNameMapping>
                ${artifact.artifactId}
            </outputFileNameMapping>
            <includes>
                <include>${project.groupId}:[project]-settings</include>
            </includes>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>
    [...]
</assembly>
```

The [assembly documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_unpackOptions) describes the `include` section as a "file and/or directory pattern for matching items to be included from an archive as it is unpacked".

The `includes` property [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet) of `dependencySet` states the following:

> If none is present, then  represents all valid values.

### Question

Does `include` work exclusively? Can I therefore expect **only** the `defaults*.properties` to be regarded as `provided` (according to this particular section)?

How do `unpackOptions-includes` interfer with the basic `includes` (last section of `dependencySet`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do `unpackOptions-includes` interfer with the basic `includes` (last section of `dependencySet`)?

They control two very different things and do not interfere together:

- Includes in [`unpackOptions`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_unpackOptions) control which files inside the artifact are to be unpacked. In your example, it means that, in every dependency that has the scope `provided`, only the files matching the pattern `defaults*.properties` will be unpacked and therefore kept.
- Includes in [`dependencySet`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet) control which artifacts are to be included in this set. In your example, only the artifacts matching `${project.groupId}:[project]-settings` will be included in this set.

Finally, the assembly descriptor you have will consider every `provided` dependency, whose name match `${project.groupId}:[project]-settings`. In each of those artifacts, it will unpack all the files matching the pattern `defaults*.properties`.

> Does `include` work exclusively?

Yes. By default, everything is included. If you override that configuration, what will be included is what you configured in this tag. Similarly, by default, nothing is excluded (and if you override that configuration, note that the exclusions rules apply on what whas previously included).